# Is there any equivalent to c++ style std::map in Julia

Tags: julia, stdmap

I am wondering if there are any equivalent `std::map` in julia... For the purpose of mapping only , I know I can maybe use a `Pair` type for example, but are there other types with better functionalities as in `std::map`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julia has [dictionary types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Dictionaries_and_sets).

The semantics are pretty similar to the one in C++.